# Powering Zynq-7000 from 28VDC

Tags: power-supply, fpga, zynq

I need to power a Zynq-7000 chip from a 28VDC bus. The chip requires a few different voltage rails, 3.3V being the highest and the core voltage of 1.0V being the lowest. Current will be approx. 2.5A for the core, less for the other rails (1.0-1.5A). Due to the large differences in voltage levels, LDOs are not really suitable so I am going to use DC/DC converters.
However, I am not sure whether the best approach is to find a chip that can do the conversion directly from 28VDC (e.g. LTM8051) or to convert down to an intermediate voltage, e.g. 5VDC, and use this voltage to source the rails. This would in turn enable the use of e.g. TPS65218D0, which is specifically made for powering FPGAs. We have also successfully used the LTM4644-1 for powering FPGA’s in the past, but this IC has a max Vin of 14VDC.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Convert to 5V. Higher voltage input buck chips are generally more expensive and you’d need larger value inductors if all converters were running of 28V.

Comment: Cost isn’t key in the application. The LTM8051 has the inductor internal to the IC and two of those would be enough to meet all the voltage rails needed. However, I am unsure if the low duty cycle of a 28V to 1V conversion would present any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Good practice in most of applications is to use switcher with combination with LDO. First you use adjustable step-down switcher that goes up to that voltage; 28V in your example and than switch it to lower voltage.  Switchers are known to make a lot of noise if they are not designed right. So because of that we add LDO in the output.

For your example you can use simple switcher as LT8609S, simulated it in LT spice. At output of your switcher you connect your LDO; LM1117 is very popular. LM117 comes in different already defined voltage level as 1V8, 3V3, 5V or you can choose adjustable one and define your preferred voltage level with simple resistor divider. But be careful the LDOs have some voltage drop, so you need to design your switcher in that way you will have at least voltage drop of the LDO bigger voltage on the output of your switcher. For example, if you need to have steady 5V power you need at least 6.2 Von the output of the switcher, if the voltage drop of LDO is 1.2V. After that you add some decoupling capacitors and you are done.

I am attaching picture of my 12V design that you can re-engineer it.

[image]